# how to get JSON as opposed to a string from jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Several attempts but no success. Can someone advice me how to get a JSON format from this little sorting script.

```
<script>
$( "button" ).button().on( "click", function() {
 var data = [];
 $( "#sortable li" ).each(function() {
   data.push( this.innerHTML );
 });
 jQuery.post(href="[% request.uri_base %]/api/sort", {data: data} , function(data){
   });
   console.log(data);
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have to move the console log inside the callback

Comment: @user1037763, if you are using php then on server side use json_encode()

Comment: i'm using perl. No issue with that. Just that what I receive as result is a string - no json format.

Comment: then use $.jsonParse(data)  , and move console.log() inside

Comment: @user1037763, sorry it is $.parseJSON(data)

Comment: I appreciate your help. Guess I'm messing things up as I couldn't get this to work yet. `jQuery.post(href="[% request.uri_base %]/api/sort", {data: data} , function(data){console.log(data)
   });`

Comment: jQuery.post(href="[% request.uri_base %]/api/sort", {data: data} , function(data){
 console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});, I am assuming you are using  json_encode() on server end

Comment: almost.. now I get: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: please add what you are getting with json

Comment: I get a string that might look confusing:
`Test - 0: $VAR1 = 'data%5B%5D=%3Cspan+id%3D%22srt-46-srt%22+class%3D%22ui-icon+ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E2+%7C%7C+Orange&data%5B%5D=%3Cspan+id%3D%22srt-1-srt%22+class%3D%22ui-icon+ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E7+%7C%7C+Apple&data%5B%5D=%3Cspan+id%3D%22srt-62-srt%22+class%3D%22ui-icon+ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s%22%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E3+%7C%7C+Mango';`
The TEST - 0 is my own reference to a test via the perl-framework I'm using. Somehow the whole html is joined in my output. In the browser I only get Unexpected end of JSON input.

Comment: are you using echo json_encode($your_varibale); in php file to send data in JSON form?

Comment: I'm using perl dancer. There is something else not right. If I put a `alert(data)` before the `jQuery.post` then I get an alert box also mentioning the HTML markup. I would expect only something like: 1-apple,2-mango,3-orange

Comment: might be try to avoid variable name data everywhere